# Sending jquery variable by POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm kinda new with jQuery's AJAX functions. I'm having a problem, this my function, its on a file head_menu.php, thats is included on the index.php file.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="dock-item" href="index.php"  class="post" id="menu01"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Home</span></a>`
<a class="dock-item" href="index.php"  class="post" id="menu02"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Create Users</span></a> `
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu01").click(function(event){
        $.post( 
        "index.php",
        { menu: "main.php" },
        this.html(data);
        }

    );
    $("#menu02").click(function(event){
        $.post( 
        "index.php",
        { menu: "create_users.php" },
        this.html(data);
        }

    );
    });
```

I'm just trying to send a post variable menu, to the index.php page to change the sidebar menu, this when we click on Home or Create Users. 
In the index.php I have this.

```
$menu = $_REQUEST['menu'];
```

How do I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data index is holding data sent to the server. You could do that:

```
<a class="dock-item" href="create_users.php" class="post"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Home</span></a>

<a class="dock-item" href="main.php" class="post"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Create Users</span></a>

 $("a.post").click(function(event){
        $.ajax( 
        url: "index.php",
        data: { menu: $(this).attr("href") },
        success: function(data) {
            $('selector').html(data);
        }
    );
     event.preventDefault();
     return false; /* Dont do what you have to do , dont go to href */
    });
```

Or change href back to index.php and put variable in any attribute you want. Maybe

```
id="create_users"
id="main"
```

and

```
 data: { menu: $(this).attr("id") + ".php" },
```

Comment: It's $.ajax. Not $.post. And we pass event, e == `undefined`

Comment: @AndreiZhamoida jQuery.post() - Description: Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Variable e is fixed. Habit to name event variables just `e`

Comment: $.post is the shortest $.ajax, but syntax different

Comment: Yes. :) He can use any of these. In his code it's $.post, so I replied also with $.post.

Comment: I meant what in $.post method you cannot pass `data: { menu: $(this).attr("href") }` as a second param. You've got mistake in syntax https://codeo.me/3DI

Comment: Oh yea,my bad. I mistake them :(

Comment: thanks for your answers. but i get a error in `data: { menu: $(this).attr("href") }, success: function(data) {` can you give an example code.

Comment: I didn't check for syntax errors.  Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF6Bw/1/).

Comment: thank for the help. the syntax is correct, but how do i get de variable in the index.php file. I tried with `echo $menu=$_POST['menu'];` ` echo $menu=$_REQUEST['menu'];` in a chrome's console i get `404 (Not Found) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
o 
p.fireWith 
e.extend.ready 
c.addEventListener.B jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2.` Can you see what's the problem?

Comment: Can you give me realtime website so I can see?

Comment: sorry its on my localhost :(. I'll try to explain.

Comment: sorry its on my localhost :(. I'll try to explain. in the index.php i have 3 function that include the other files. the head_menu, the side_menu and the main_content. I need 3 variables to control those parts. My problem is if you select something in the head_menu, like users_management, the side_menu changes according to that. when i select the head_menu, if I `echo $_POST['menu'];`in index.php i get nothing..

Comment: You can specify type: "GET" or type: "POST". Default is "GET" so you need to use $_GET['menu'] or $_REQUEST['menu']

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.. here is the full code of the 2 files.https://codeo.me/3E1

Answer (score -1):

```
<a class="dock-item" href="index.php" class="post" id="menu01"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Home</span></a>

<a class="dock-item" href="index.php" class="post" id="menu02"><img src="images/home.png" alt="home" /><span>Create Users</span></a>

<script>
$.customPOST = function(data,callback){
  $.post('index.php',data,callback,'json');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu01").click(function(){
        $.customPOST({menu: "main.php",function(response){
         //server will return an OBJECT called "response"
         //in "index.php" you will need to use json_encode();
         //in order to return a response to the client
         //json_encode(); must have an array as argument
         //the array must be in the form : 'key' => 'value'
         //on the server side you will have $_POST['menu'}
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#menu02").click(function(){
        $.customPOST({menu: "create_users.php",function(response){
         //server will return an OBJECT called "response"
         //in "index.php" you will need to use json_encode();
         //in order to return a response to the client
         //json_encode(); must have an array as argument
         //the array must be in the form : 'key' => 'value'
         //on the server side you will have $_POST['menu'}
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But in the index.php i just put `json_encode(); $menu=$_POST['menu'];` to get the variable?

Comment: then you put : json_encode(array());
since you will not need a response from the server.
to get the variable on the server side put this :
if(isset($_POST['menu'])){
  $menu = $_POST['menu'];
  //your actions here
}